# How to fix this AbpException: Could not find the bundle file '/libs/abp/core/abp.css' for the bundle 'LeptonXLite.Global' at ABP.IO Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, abp

#### Environment

- April 2023, Windows 11, Visual Studio 22.
- NET Core 7
- ABP CLI 7.1.1
- npm 8.17.8
- Yarn 3.5.0

#### Steps

- `abp new TodoApp`, creates a new ABP Solution.
- Restore packages.
- Run `TodoApp.DbMigrator` project, for full DB creation.
- Excecute solution running `TodoApp.Web` project.
- Exception is thrown.

#### Problem

- In .Web project, the `/wwwroot/libs/` folder is empty.
- Exception is thrown.

#### Exception thrown

[image]

Raw exception details:

```
Volo.Abp.AbpException: Could not find the bundle file '/libs/abp/core/abp.css' for the bundle 'LeptonXLite.Global'!
   at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Bundling.TagHelpers.AbpTagHelperResourceService.ProcessAsync(ViewContext viewContext, TagHelper tagHelper, TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output, List`1 bundleItems, String bundleName)
   at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Bundling.TagHelpers.AbpBundleTagHelperService`2.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.<RunAsync>g__Awaited|0_0(Task task, TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext, Int32 i, Int32 count)
   at AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Themes_LeptonXLite_Layouts_Application.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync()
   at AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Themes_LeptonXLite_Layouts_Application.ExecuteAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderLayoutAsync(ViewContext context, ViewBufferTextWriter bodyWriter)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Serilog.AbpSerilogMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<<UseMiddlewareInterface>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Auditing.AbpAuditingMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
   at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Auditing.AbpAuditingMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<<UseMiddlewareInterface>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Uow.AbpUnitOfWorkMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<<UseMiddlewareInterface>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.ExceptionHandling.AbpExceptionHandlingMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
   at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.ExceptionHandling.AbpExceptionHandlingMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<<UseMiddlewareInterface>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.MultiTenancy.MultiTenancyMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<<UseMiddlewareInterface>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ApplicationBuilderAbpOpenIddictMiddlewareExtension.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<UseAbpOpenIddictValidation>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitMatcher|8_0(EndpointRoutingMiddleware middleware, HttpContext httpContext, Task`1 matcherTask)
   at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Tracing.AbpCorrelationIdMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<<UseMiddlewareInterface>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.RequestLocalization.AbpRequestLocalizationMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<<UseMiddlewareInterface>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

#### Possible solutions

- `abp install-libs` does not work.

#### Question

How do I solve it? It looks like I followed all the steps as explained in the official abp.io tutorial:
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Tutorials/Todo/Index?UI=MVC&DB=EF

Comment: I'll be adding additional details to this question, for the sake of improvement. Please, do add any suggestions or criticism to it in the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm reproducing this solution: https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/15411#issuecomment-1383249791 which I was able to implement after some hours of research.

- Run `abp install-libs` from the console at root solution level (`Solution 'BookStore'`, for example), or at your main root web project level (`BookStore.Web`, for example).

  - You may want to [install and use yarn](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/) (recommended), but the command should work with `npm` the same.

#### SOLUTION STEPS

In case you have already run `abp install-libs`:

0. Delete `.yarn` folder, `.pnp.cjs` file, `yarn.lock` file

Whatever the case:

1. Add a new file with name: `.yarnrc.yml` in the root folder.
2. Add this single line of content to `.yarnrc.yml`: `nodeLinker: node-modules`
3. Run `abp install-libs` from the console.
4. Rebuild and run the Web project, `TodoApp.Web`

After cleaning, web project looks like this:

[image]

After `abp install-libs` run, web project looks like:

[image]

Note, there is a folder `node_modules` and a the folder: `.Web\wwwroot\libs` has content in it.

#### Result

[image]

Comment: Give @carloswm85 two cookies